# PHP - function easter_date is not callable

Tags: php

A template caused my site to behave weird and only the header was loaded. I discovered that there are a few lines calling the function `easter_date`. If the function is getting called then my site breaks.

So the function does not seem to exist. So I added the line `if (!is_callable('easter_date')) return false;` and it actually returned false.

I am running on PHP 5.6.40. It says that `easter_date` is available in PHP 4, 5 and 7

Why does `easter_date` not exist?

**Example Code:**

```
    $easter_d = date("d", easter_date($datum[0]));
    $easter_m = date("m", easter_date($datum[0]));
```

Comment: Add a `\\` before the function for it look in the global namespace. See if that solves it.

Comment: The function is part of the calendar extension, see its manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/calendar.installation.php

Comment: You never provided a snippet of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Ensure you have installed the [extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/calendar.installation.php)
2. Try and add a `\` before the function to make it search the global namespace for the function

Comment: Is there a way to install the extension after php is already installed? I am running on linux